# SQL Server design

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

I am trying to build a c# application with visual studio. One of my design problems is this:

- A costumer creates a request(For some service), which will be stored on a "Requests Table" in the database.
- Every company can make a "bid", where it will give the service for price X.
- The student will then look at each request and choose the one which suits him best.

Thus, every "bid" needs to keep the Company name, and the bid price.

How can i store the "bids" on an SQL server? 
I thought of creating a Table for each request which stores the bids, but it seems to take a lot of space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a table for each request. You should be done with these tables:

Customers: CustomerId

Services: ServiceId

Requests: CustomerId, ServiceId

Companies: CompanyId

Bids: CompanyId, RequestId

Comment: I am pretty new to sql servers, but won't it take a lot of time if I want to show a costumer the list of his requests? Will require going over all the requests.

Comment: You could use indexes and even table partitions to increase performance, but then the answer will be too broad. If you are unsure, it's better to hire an experienced professional for this.

Comment: I am willing to learn and evolve, if you wish to give me sources or tools to help me with this specific problem or with SQL in general, will be glad :)

Comment: @ShahafNahmias Mastering database design and optimization is a long path, but luckily you have a bunch of information on MSDN about it

Answer (score 0):

since you are new to sql servers[Database Normalization forms](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

you should be aware of normalization forms and rest will be ok in terms of db design